# sscanf expression in C - how to get everything after the last slash?

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I'm having trouble coming up with an expression that will get me the part of the string after the last slash.

Let's say I have `argv[1] = "HIsomething:01/02/03.file";`

How do I get sscanf to store only what's written after the last slash? ( "03.file" in this example)?  The number of slashes is not fixed.

I know that if I were to write

```
char string [100];

sscanf(argv[1], "HIsomething:%99[^\n]", string);
```

I would probably get "01/02/03.file" stored in the string.

And I can't just type it in manually since the argument could be different and I need an universal solution for just getting everything after the last slash.

Comment: You can't do it with *scanf alone. Write a proper parser, or just use `strrchr`.

Comment: Can you rely on the input always to contain the *same number* of slashes (i.e. two)?

Comment: Nope I can't. It could be more or it could be less slashes.

Comment: Then [`s`]`scanf()` cannot do this job.  I concur with the recommendations to use `strchr()`; if your matching requirements were more elaborate then I might have suggested a regular expression library such as PCRE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `sscanf()`, use `strrchr(3)`

> The strrchr() function returns a pointer to the last occurrence of the character c in the string s.

```c
char *str;
str = strrchr(argv[1], '/');
if (str != NULL) {
    str++; /* step over the slash */
}
```

NOTE: the resulting value of `str` will be either `NULL` or will point *into* your `argv[1]` string. At this point, if you really need a copy (perhaps to modify), you could use `strdup(3)`